# Trigger a function once 2 inputs are set and then afterwards if either of the value changes in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-input

I have a component with 2 inputs (or mor) and I want to:

1. Trigger a method X the first time, when both value are set and exists
2. Trigger a method X each time, if either one of the both value changes

```
<some-cmp [itemid]="activeItemId$ | async" [userId]="activeUserId$ | async"></some-cmp>
```

Both values can change at any time, so I figured using `rxjs` to build a stream lets me control everything. My current solution seems a bit hacky and is difficult to test. I use 2 `BehaviourSubjects` and `combineLatest` with a `debounceTime`.

```
@Input() set itemId (id){this.itemId$.next(id)};
@Input() set userId (id){this.userId$.next(id)};

itemId$ = new BehaviourSubject$(null);
userId$ = new BehaviourSubbject$(null);

ngOnInt(){
    combineLatest([
        this.itemId$.pipe(filter(item=>item!===null)),
        this.userId$.pipe(filter(item=>item!===null))
    ]).pipe(
        debounceTime(10),
        switchMap(...)
    ).subscribe(...)
}
```

So my question are

1. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this behavior?
2. Is there a way to avoid the `debounceTime`, which makes testing difficult?

The `debounceTime` is used in case both value do arrive at the same time and I don't want `combineLatest` to trigger the method twice.

Comment: fyi, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5689 or https://github.com/insidewhy/observable-input

Comment: You could define one `Subject` that emits an object with properties for the itemId and userId. That might simplify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in using `combineLatest`, it will only emit the first time after each source has emitted once and then will emit any time any source emits.

> Is there a way to avoid the debounceTime. [It] is used in case both value do arrive at the same time and I don't want combineLatest to trigger the method twice.

Maybe `debounceTime` isn't necessary due to the initial behavior of `combineLatest`; it will not emit the first time until all sources emit.  However if you typically receive subsequent emissions from both sources that occur within a short timeframe, use of `debounceTime` may be an appropriate optimization.

> Is there a more elegant way to achieve this behavior?

I think your code is fine.  However, it may not be necessary to use `BehaviorSubject` since you aren't really using the default value.  You could use plain `Subject` or [`ReplaySubject(1)`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject).

You could assign the result of your `combineLatest` to another variable and subscribe to that inside `ngOnInit` or use the `async` pipe in the template:

```js
@Input() set itemId (id){ this.itemId$.next(id) };
@Input() set userId (id){ this.userId$.next(id) };

itemId$ = new Subject<string>();
userId$ = new Subject<string>();

data$ = combineLatest([
    this.itemId$.pipe(filter(i => !!i)),
    this.userId$.pipe(filter(i => !!i))
]).pipe(
    debounceTime(10),
    switchMap(...)
);

ngOnInit() {
  this.data$.subscribe(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides `ngOnChanges` hook which can be used in this scenario. It'll trigger `ngOnChanges` method whenever there's a change in any of the inputs of the component.

Below is an example of how this can be achieved:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() itemId: any;
  
    @Input() userId: any;
  
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      const change = changes.itemId || changes.userId;
  
      if (change && change.currentValue !== change.previousValue) {
        this.doSomething();
      }
    }
  
    private doSomething() {
      // Your logic goes here
    }
  }
```

Your HTML will now look clean and you can get rid of `async` as well:

```
<some-cmp [itemid]="itemId" [userId]="userId"></some-cmp>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew of ngOnChanges, but all it does is to replace the setters, since it cannot track the state that both values exists.

Comment: @HanChe Actually, `ngOnChanges` is quite powerful. The changes that it receives follow the `SimpleChange` interface (https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChange) that tracks all the important info like prrevValue, currentValue, isFirstChange, etc for every input prop. Hence, it definitely suits this problem IMO.